# How to retrieve data from a XML using Nokogiri

Tags: ruby, xml, parsing, nokogiri, screen-scraping

I am trying to scrape a web page and extract a unique identifier for each listing such as "listing_328".

This is raw data from the Firefox inspector:

```
<div id="result_container" class="listings js-listings-container">
  <div class="listing-item result js-listing-item" id="listing_328">
  <div class="listing-item result js-listing-item" id="listing_389">
  <div class="listing-item result js-listing-item" id="listing_129">
```

There are six listings total.

I think this gets the children:

```
elements = parsed_page.xpath('//div[@id="result_container"]/div');
```

Here is the basic code to scrape the page:

```
require 'nokogiri'
require 'byebug'
require 'webdrivers'
require 'watir'

def scraper

   url ="....."
   browser = Watir::Browser.new :firefox  
   browser.goto(url)
   sleep(5)

   parsed_page = Nokogiri::HTML(browser.html)

   byebug

end

scraper
browser.close
```

`parsed_page` is:

```
#<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x3fe0bfc48ea4 name="div" attributes=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Attr:0x3fe0bfc48d8c name="id" value="result_container">, #<Nokogiri::XML::Attr:0x3fe0bfc48d64 name="class" value="listings js-listings-container">] children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x3fe0bfc4d51c "\n  ">, #<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x3fe0bfc4d24c name="div" attributes=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Attr:0x3fe0bfc4d0f8 name="class" value="listing-item result js-listing-item">, #<Nokogiri::XML::Attr:0x3fe0bfc4d0bc name="id" value="listing_328">]
```

I am looking to extract the `listing_item` values "listing_328" "listing_389" etc.

I can dump the `parsed_page` to text and extract the identifier.

I don't get a match with:

```
elements.find {|n| puts n.inner_html.match(/(id=.listing_\d\d\d)/)}
```

but I do get a match elsewhere in elements in a different format.

```
elements.find {|n| puts n.inner_html.match(/data-listing-id=.(\d\d\d)/)}
```

Can I do better?

I don't have the id for the children.

Comment: Be careful trusting the inspector inside a browser. That HTML can be very different that what Nokogiri sees when the page is passed to it because JavaScript can modify the page which then the browser will show you. Instead always download the page using `wget` or `curl` or something similar, open it in your text editor and look at it.

Comment: "[What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)"

Answer (score 1):

You can get those with:

```
parsed_page.search('.listing-item').map{ |div| div['id'] }
```

Comment: parsed_page.search('.listing-item').map{ |div| div['id'] }
["listing_328", "listing_389", "listing_129", "listing_125", "listing_394", "listing_341"] Awesome, thanks